# Post-Hoc Scheffe Test (Agricolae). Where are the coefficients?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, multiple-comparisons, ancova, post-hoc

I know this is fundamental. Please forgive me. I am new to R.
I ran the Scheffe post-hoc test after ANCOVA using "scheffe.test" from package "Agricolae". I got the following output:

```
    > # Post-Hoc
> library(agricolae)
Warning message:
package ‘agricolae’ was built under R version 3.4.2 
> 
> # Qstorm ~ LandUse*Rainfall
> comparison <- scheffe.test(r3,"LandUse", group=FALSE, console=TRUE,
+ main="Qstorm among different LandUse*Rainfall")

Study: Qstorm among different LandUse*Rainfall

Scheffe Test for Qstorm 

Mean Square Error  : 64.70584 

LandUse,  means

      Qstorm       std   r     Min      Max
LF2 9.413656 13.234435  82 0.00000 64.90228
LF3 6.509084 10.008503 123 0.00000 46.30602
OP  4.676709  6.863499 121 0.00019 30.18665
VJR 5.710812 10.682185  66 0.00062 45.31401

Alpha: 0.05 ; DF Error: 384 
Critical Value of F: 2.628149 

Comparison between treatments means

          Difference pvalue sig        LCL      UCL
LF2 - LF3  2.9045716 0.0949   . -0.4238827 6.233026
LF2 - OP   4.7369466 0.0009 ***  1.3975073 8.076386
LF2 - VJR  3.7028437 0.0531   . -0.1579546 7.563642
LF3 - OP   1.8323751 0.3682     -1.1569616 4.821712
LF3 - VJR  0.7982721 0.9354     -2.7640364 4.360581
OP - VJR  -1.0341029 0.8718     -4.6066775 2.538472
```

May I ask, how do i interpret this results? More specifically, which are the coefficient of slope and coefficient of intercept to be substituted into the model?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second table of the results provides the pairwise comparison of the means, for all possible combination of groups. The comparison needs to be done on the 'Difference' column from the second table with the 'Critical value of F', and the p-values are generated based on that. Simply check the p-value column, if it is less than 0.05, it indicates the mean for the two groups are different.

In your example 'LF2 - OP' has a p-value of 0.0009, which says that the mean of groups 'LF2' and 'OP' are significantly different.